# Using masks on abnormally sized words

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am writing some code where I need to code/decode 56-bit (7-byte) words and 112-bit (14-byte) words.

I am used to dealing with 32-bit words.  If I need to extract bits 23-25 from a word I just do this:

```
int unpackBits23To25( uint32_t word )
{
    return (word>>22) & 0x7;
}
```

or in a more generic manner like this:

```
int unpackBits( uint8_t word[14], int startbit, int endbit )
{
  int mask = (0x1 << (endbit - startbit + 1)) - 1;
  return (word >> (startbit - 1)) & mask;
}
```

It's fairly easy to see what I'm trying to do (a shift and a mask). But what about if I'm extracting bits 23-25 from a 112-bit word?  Instead of using `uint32_t` I would need to use something else.  A `uint64_t` would work for 56-bit words, but since I also have 112 bit words, I'll need to store it in an array of something.  `uint8_t[14]` is probably my best bet.

```
int unpackBits23To25( uint8_t word[14] )
{
  return ((word[5] >> 3) & 0x1) | ((word[6] << 1) & 0x6);
}
```

That wasn't **too** hard to write, but is completely illegible if you want to read/troubleshoot it.  I haven't tried the generic solution yet, but I have a feeling that it's going to be a monster.

How would you recommend to do bit-wise operations on obscure word-sizes?

Comment: No magic is expected here. If the bit operation is affecting all of the bytes (like in shift) you will have to iterate all of them, ant propagate the boundary bits manually.

Comment: Don't you have `uint64_t` available?

Comment: @Peri461 Shift (and other bitwise) operators are undefined on non-integer types.

Comment: Pad to some reasonable size. 112 bits fit into `unsigned __int128` if your compiler provides it, otherwise use 2 `uint64_t`. I wouldn't want to use `uint8_t` here, why have more elements than needed...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Unless you have to deal with endianness issues. Then it is arguably better to use a `uint8_t[]`.

Comment: @rodrigo why? If you only do operations (bitwise, arithmetic, ...), you don't care. And if you want to serialize, well, I'd opt for converting as needed. Less hassle, especially if you can *completely* avoid using an array.

Comment: Note that a generic and fully general bit-selection function must be prepared for the possibility that a call requests *all bits* of the subject number.  Such a function's return type needs to be able to accommodate that, and your example signature does not appear to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generic way to extract a single bit from a byte array treated as a bit array:

```
uint8_t value = (word[bit/8] & (1 << (bit%8)) != 0;
```

For a given range of bits to extract, you can loop through each bit and place them into a result:

```
uint32_t unpackBits( uint8_t word[14], int startbit, int endbit )
{
    uint32_t result;
    int i;

    for (result = 0, i = endbit; i >= startbit; i--) {
        uint8_t value = (word[i/8U] & (1 << (i%8U)) != 0;
        result = (result << 1) | value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's easier than expected.

Comment: Minor: Negative values for `startbit, endbit` are a problem and can make for less efficient code with `i/8, i%8` which likely  emit signed division/remainder vs the always efficient unsigned div/rem 8.  Could use `unsigned` bit values and/or `8u` instead of `8`.

Comment: @chux Using a `u` suffix on the divisors is probably the way to go.  The problem with using unsigned in this case is because we are counting down instead of up.  If we use unsigned values and `startbit` is 0, the comparison is always true and we have an infinite loop.